# MongoDB server running, I get "mongo: command not found"

Tags: mongodb

I`ve started mongoDB and it seems like its running fine, I think (see message below)? Then I open a new terminal window and I try to use the "mongo" command I get the following message:

-bash: mongo: command not found

When I try commands such as "use newtest", it says

-bash: use: command not found

My Path:

PATH=/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

Here is the message when I start mongoDB:

```html
myname-MacBook-Air:~ myname$ mongod
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=581 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=myname-MacBook-Air.local
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519475976:405758][581:0x7fff95b02340], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 4/3200
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519475976:408878][581:0x7fff95b02340], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 5
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1519475976:564148][581:0x7fff95b02340], txn-recover: Recovering log 5 through 5
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
```

What am I doing wrong here to start mongodB? Or am I misunderstanding it? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Your path is pointing to the npm global binaries. Point them to path of your mongodb installation e.g. export PATH = $PATH:$HOME/mongo/bin

Comment: Thanks! But if I do not point to the global bin, then I wont be able to use commands such as NPM and NG. Is it possible to add both paths?